# OpenAI GymのCartpoleのデモがすぐ消えてしまいます

Tags: python

Ubuntu 16.04にて以下をターミナルから実行すると画像がすぐ消えてしまいます:

```
import gym
env = gym.make('MsPacman-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    time.sleep(0.1)　#他のサイトでこれを入れれば消えないと言ってましたが
    env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
```

MountainCar、MsPacmanも同じく一瞬で消えます。
因みにOpenAI自体の説明はこちらからもらいました：https://gym.openai.com/docs/

Comment: 自己解決できたようで何よりです。もしよろしければ、ご自身の回答に解決マークをつけてください。そうするとこの質問のステータスが解決済みに変更されます。

Comment: 自分自身の質問を承認するには48時間待つ必要があります。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import gym
import time #追加のコード
env = gym.make('MsPacman-v0')
env.reset()
for _ in range(1000):
    env.render()
    time.sleep(0.1)　#他のサイトでこれを入れれば消えないと言ってましたが
    env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action
```

2行目で改善されました。